# Cómo puedo cancelar el llamando de un evento onclick? Android Studio.

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick, onclicklistener

Hay alguna forma, de que por tiempo, yo pueda cancelar un llamado de un onclik? ejemplo, yo quise actualizar mediante un boton, pero este proceso de busqueda en la base de datos se esta tardando demasiado, yo quisiera cancelar este llamando para que la persona no tenga que esperar tanto tiempo y asi pueda seguir usando su aplicacion.

Comment: Recuerda agregar el código que has tratado, puede ser de ayuda a la comunidad para brindarte una solución

Answer (score 1):

Lo que yo haría sería meter la funcionalidad dentro de un AsynTask que luego lo podrías cancelar con una llamada a un botón cancel.

algo así:

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        btnOK.setEnabled(false); 
        btnCancel.setEnable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... values) {
        DoYourTaskFunctionality();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
        btnOK.setEnabled(true); 
        btnCancel.setEnable(false);
    }
}
```

Y en el OnClick de la clase (si  implementas OnClickListener):

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.btnOK:
                task = new MyTask().execute(0);
                break;
            case R.id.btnCancel:
                if (task != null) task.cancel(true);
                break;               
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

De todos modos te aconsejo que le eches un ojo al manual de AsynTask https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask